# Iterating over .csv with .bat file and copy its content to the clipboard

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd

I want to create a .bat file that helps me iterate through my .csv file. I don't know the number of the columns or the rows. All I know is the seperator is semicolon.

So my.csv example:

```
a;b;c
1qw;ads;f
ads;d;da
ads;asfas;afs
```

The code that I tried:

```
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ teszt2.csv"`) do (
    set /p="var=%%a"|clip
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "var=!var:*:=!"
    echo(!var!
    ENDLOCAL
)
```

...but it is not good because it gives back only the last row so if I press CTRL + V after running the batch file the result will be: var=4:ads;asfas;afs

I want to save all the data to my clipboard.

Any solution? Thank you!

Comment: What do you want in the clipboard? Do you want `a`, `lqw`, `ads` and `ads` with each value on a separate line (field values of first data column in CSV file) or do you want them on one line in clipboard with `a;lqw;ads;ads`? Your batch file example does not make any sense for me. Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `clip /?` and read the output help. Then run `for /?` and read again the output help carefully and completely from top of first to bottom of last page.

Comment: I want all the data to be on my clipboard just the way it looks like in the .csv file. All the columns and rows.

Comment: Okay, after execution of `clip /?` and reading the help you should know the solution: `clip < teszt2.csv`. That's it. Or you use `if exist "teszt2.csv" %SystemRoot%\System32\clip.exe < "teszt2.csv"`. There is no __FOR__ loop necessary to copy the contents of a text file not encoded with UTF-16 LE to clipboard. Just the execution of `clip.exe` with an input redirection to read the text data from a file.

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped me a lot. If you are saying it's not the proper way to copy .csv content to the clipboard then I'm looking for another solution with PowerShell - because sometimes I should processing files with the size of 50 Mb so I am afraid it will fail.

Comment: Remember to always read the help files for commands before you ask questions.  It makes a person look quite ignorant when they don't.  Directly from the help file: `CLIP < README.TXT   Places a copy of the text from readme.txt on to the Windows clipboard.`

Comment: Neither the Microsoft documentation for the [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) [clip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/clip) nor the SS64 [Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/) documentation for the command [clip](https://ss64.com/nt/clip.html) contain any information about file size limit. So I created with text editor UltraEdit a CSV file with 58 622 440 bytes which is about 55.9 [GiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte) with 772800 lines.

Comment: Then I used `clip < test_input.csv` and needed to wait several minutes until `clip.exe` finished. It reads the large CSV file `test_input.csv` in blocks of just 1024 bytes (1 KiB) and appends each block to the already read data which makes the process very slow on large files (millions of memory reallocations and data copying in memory). But `clip.exe` finally finished. Then I created in UltraEdit a new file, pasted the clipboard content and saved the file as `test_output.csv`. A binary comparison of the two files return no difference. So no real problem with such a large CSV file.

Comment: I don't know if the PowerShell cmdlet [Set-Clipboard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard) documented also on [SS64](https://ss64.com/ps/set-clipboard.html) is faster on copying a large file to the clipboard. PowerShell 3.0 or a newer version is required, but on Windows 7 is installed by default only PowerShell 2.0 and I have intentionally never updated to a newer version. You can do the PowerShell speed test by yourself. UltraEdit copies the entire CSV file data in a fraction of a second to clipboard after Ctrl+O and Ctrl+A.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. The reason for using this CSV reading method because I needed it in a VBA modul so this will do the job. Unfortunately stackoverflowed banned my ability to write new question. I don't know why and how to solve it but hope I still can write comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to copy *"as is"* your .csv into the clipboard, simply run

```
type "C:\path_to_your\my.csv" | clip
```

If you wish to remove the `;` character and put a space then:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("usedata\tmp1.txt") do (
   set "line=%%a"
   set "line=!line:;= !"
   echo/!line!>>tmp
)
type tmp | clip & del /q tmp


:end
endlocal
exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you used `DisableDelayedExpansion`. I think you should use `EnableDelayedExpansion`.

I adjusted the code a little (and used another name for the .csv):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set clipboard=
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ test.csv"`) do (
    set clipboard=!clipboard! "var=%%a"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "var=!var:*:=!"
    echo(!var!
    ENDLOCAL
)
echo %clipboard%
echo %clipboard% | clip
```

With this code, a .csv containing this:

```
a;b;c
1qw;ads;f
ads;d;da
ads;asfas;afs
```

gets stored in clipboard like this:

```
 "var=1:a;b;c" "var=2:1qw;ads;f" "var=3:ads;d;da" "var=4:ads;asfas;afs"
```